# MVC Razor null check on model throwing null exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Hi I am new to MVC I am trying to disable a button if a few textboxfor fields are not entered or are null. I have tried the following code below but no luck, I get an object null error.

```
@if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(modelData.Email))
{
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" onclick="JavascriptFunction()" disabled="disabled" />
}
else
{
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" onclick="JavascriptFunction()" />
}
```

HTML Text box definition

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @placeholder = "example: dlamini@gmail.com", @class = "form-control", id = "message", onkeypress = "capLock(event)" })
```

This happens when the `Registration.cshtml` page loads, please assist.

Answer (score 1):

I think `modelData` must be null. Depending on your .NET version, you could try either

```
@if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(modelData?.Email))
```

or

```
@if (modelData != null && String.IsNullOrEmpty(modelData.Email))
```